# Why is telethon showing an error when trying to get users from a telegram group?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon, mtproto

I am trying to get users from a group using a telegram bot . I am using python's telethon library for this purpose . Here is the code and the full error message -

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
API_ID = 123
API_HASH = '##'  
BOT_TOKEN  ="##" 
bot = TelegramClient('bot', API_ID, API_HASH)
bot.start(bot_token=BOT_TOKEN) 
async def Get_Random():
    users = await bot.get_participants(-123)
    print(users[0].first_name)
    for user in users:
        if user.username is not None:
            print(user.username)
bot.loop.run_until_complete(Get_Random())
```

Full error -

```
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.PeerIdInvalidError: An invalid Peer was used. Make sure to pass the right peer type and that the value is valid (for instance, bots cannot start conversations) (caused by GetFullChatRequest)
```

Bot is already an admin of the group .

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is stuck and viewing this , You need to be part of the telegram group for which you are fetching the data . Joining that telegram group resolved my error .